# How to set permanatly flutter sdk path in anroid studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, sdk

Everything is installed completely. Bash file is correct.But whenever I create new flutter application by default flutter SDK field is black every time i need to set flutter SDK path for new application.
My question is there are any method to fix blank flutter SDK path when create new flutter application in android studio?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter` and set the `Flutter SDK path`